# How do I add an AudioWorkletProcessor to work with it in audioWorkletNode in Dart?

Tags: dart, web-audio-api

In pure **JS** I can do it:

```js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(new Audio());

await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('./my-processor.js');
const processorNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'my-processor');

source.connect(processorNode);
processorNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

In **Dart** I can not do it:

```
var audioContext = AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(AudioElement());

audioContext.audioWorklet // The getter 'audioWorklet' isn't defined for the class 'AudioContext'.
var processorNode = AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'my-processor');

source.connectNode(processorNode);
processorNode.connectNode(audioContext.destination);
```

I cannot find the `audioWorklet` property in the `AudioContext` class.
I tried unsuccessfully to find in the documentation where else an `audioWorklet` or `addModule` could be located.

How do I add an `AudioWorkletProcessor` to work with it in `audioWorkletNode` in Dart?

Comment: "Window" class has worklet property. ( not the context )  see https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-html/Window/audioWorklet.html

Comment: @robert-rowntree Thanks, yes, indeed, but unfortunately `audioWorklet` does not have the `addModule` property here.
I can not understand how to use this `audioWorklet`

Comment: just a guess. if u not satisfied with dart class implementation , i think you can switch to webview/node where u have working audio worklets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there isn't a method or property in a JS interop object you can use the `dart:js_util`:

```dart
import 'package:js/js_util.dart' as jsu;

var worklet = jsu.getProperty(audioContext, 'audioWorklet'));

jsu.callMethod(worklet, 'addModule', ['./my-processor.js']));
```